# JQuery datatable get column attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am creating `datatable` and adding rows through `jQuery` like below. First column in the datatable is radio button.

```
 var hostTable = $('#hostTable').DataTable();
 var newRow = "<tr><td><input name='hosts' type='radio' value='-1'/></td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr>";
 hostTable.row.add($(newRow)).draw(false);
```

On button click, I would like to get `name` for the radio button. I have following code, but getting

```
TypeError: settings.aoColumns[column].attr is not a function
```

Here is the code:

```
 hostTable.columns().iterator('column', function (settings, column) {
                            alert(settings.aoColumns[column]);
                            var tempId = settings.aoColumns[column].attr('name');
                            alert(tempId);
                        });
```

How can I get `attr` of a first `td` from `datatable`? Any help would be appreciated.

Note: I am using latest `datatable`, so not using any fn.. functions.

Comment: Could you post your html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that .attr() is a jQuery method. Make sure you include this library in your project and try wrapping your element in a jQuery object before calling the function.

```
var tempId = $(settings.aoColumns[column]).attr('name');
```

Comment: Thanks! Let me try it.